# mocking elasticclient and setting up indexasync

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, moq, xunit

I have gone through examples here of mocking ElasticClient and how to setup for search or searchasync methods.

How would one go about setting up methods such as IndexAsync() or IndexManyAsync().

My code is as follows:

```
public void Test()
{ 
  
        var mockElasticClient = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
        mockElasticClient.Setup(x => x.IndexAsync(It.IsAny <Func<IndexDescriptor<Model>, IIndexRequest<ElasticVariant>>>));
}
```

With this the error I get is : "The type arguments for method IElasticClient.IndexAsync(IIndexRequest, cancellationToken) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type argument explicitly.

When I provide cancellation token then the above error goes but instead I get cannot convert from threading cancellation token.
Following is the code with cancellation token.

```
public void Test()
    { 
      
            var mockElasticClient = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
            mockElasticClient.Setup(x => x.IndexAsync(It.IsAny <Func<IndexDescriptor<Model>, IIndexRequest<ElasticVariant>>>, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by following:

```
 var mockElasticClient = new Mock<IElasticClient>();
 var mockResponse = new Mock<IndexResponse>();
 mockElasticClient.Setup(y =>
     y.IndexAsync<Model>(It.IsAny<Model>(), It.IsAny<Func<IndexDescriptor<Model>, 
                         IIndexRequest<Model>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken()))
.ReturnsAsync(mockResponse.Object);
```

Comment: Suggestion for those that come across this, a closing bracket is missed at the end of CancellationToken(). Should be It.IsAny<CancellationToken()>.